# How to only use jquery .css() on a specific media query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

When a user's browser has a width of less than 1160px, a media query is setup to collapse my site's right sidebar. They can get it back by clicking on a little arrow and then it will overlap the content (absolute positioning).

Anyway, I used the following jQuery to achieve this:

```
$('.right_sidebar_preview').on('click', function() {
     $('.right_sidebar_preview').css('display', 'none');
     $('.right_sidebar').css('display', 'block');
});
$('.right_sidebar').on('click', function() {
     $('.right_sidebar_preview').css('display', 'block');
     $('.right_sidebar').css('display', 'none');
});
```

So basically I already have the preview hidden when the browser is larger than 1160px and the sidebar is visible, in the media query I have it set up so when it's below 1160px, the sidebar becomes invisible and the "sidebar preview" is shown which users can click to make it bigger.

CSS:

```
.right_sidebar {
  width: 242px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #d8e1ef;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
.right_sidebar_preview {
  display: none;
}
@media(max-width:1160px) {
  .right_sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  .right_sidebar_preview {
    display: block;
    background-color: #d8e1ef;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 15px;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

My question is, when I use the code above, let's say we're in the less than 1160px media query, I'll open the sidebar then collapse it again, and when I stretch my browser out to go back, it also closed the sidebar on the greater than 1160px media query.

So is there anyway I can use .css() (or an alternative method) to point at a specific media query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not manipulate the CSS `display:` property. Instead, use CSS classes to control the visibility of sidebar and its handle. This way you can use your media query to control whether an element displays or not.

In the following demo, click the "Full page" button to see how this works on screens > 1160px.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.right_sidebar, .right_preview').on('click', function() {
    $('.right_sidebar, .right_preview').toggleClass('lt-1160-hide lt-1160-show');
  });
});
```

```css
.right_sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: papayawhip;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.right_preview {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: palegoldenrod;
  float: left;
  display: none;
}
@media(max-width: 1160px) {
  /* note: the following rules do not apply on larger screens */
  .right_sidebar.lt-1160-show, .right_preview.lt-1160-show {
    display: block;
  }
  .right_sidebar.lt-1160-hide, .right_preview.lt-1160-hide {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="right_sidebar lt-1160-hide">Sidebar</div>
<div class="right_preview lt-1160-show">&rsaquo;</div>
```

Comment: Like using .addClass()? Wouldn't that just give me the same result if I was to add .css() to their current class?

Comment: @Brad: No, it would not, if as Salman said you set up your classes to only affect the element when the media query is matched …

Comment: The point is that you use add/remove class functions instead of `.css("display")`; then in your stylesheet you set rules so that the sidebar is always visible and previous button is always hidden on larger screens. I'll try to add an example.

Comment: Thanks a ton Salman, just figured it out as well. Also learned papayawhip is a color today. Chosen as best answer.

Answer (score 1):

On a recent project, I had to process a single function in jQuery based on the browser size. Initially I was going to check the device width was applicable to a mobile device (320px):

**jQuery**

```
$(window).resize(function(){

       if ($(window).width() <= 320) {  

              // your code here

       }     

});
```

or

```
$(window).resize(function(){     

       if ($('header').width() == 320 ){

              // your code here

       }

});
```

Comment: I still run into the same issue. Your code works except when I collapse the sidebar (in the less than 1160px) it than shows collapse in the greater than 1160, and I always want it to be showing in that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   if ($(window).width() <= 1160){  
      // lets party
   }    
});
```

Comment: I still run into the same issue. Your code works except when I collapse the sidebar (in the less than 1160px) it than shows collapse in the greater than 1160, and I always want it to be showing in that.